# Routing between Pages

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Hey  I would like to know. how can I create a routing between number of pages.
I have an index page and I want to route to other pages in my views folder which are other HTML pages.
How can I do it without using angularjs routing system.

Comment: What do you mean by withour routing system?You dont want to use ngoute

Comment: I mean without installing angularjs into the app. I am looking for simple solutions, I need to route between only 4 pages, I don't need all the power of angularjs routing system, to powerfull for my needs right now.

Comment: you can use acnhor  tag

Comment: You want to create a link to another page?

Answer (score 1):

Here some links to pages/files using the `a` tag.

**HTML link**

```
<a href="linktoyourpage" >Link</a>
```

**HTML link to a file**

```
<a href="linktoyourfile.html" >Link</a>
```

**HTML link to a file in folder**

```
<a href="folder/linktoyourfile.html" >Link</a>
```

**HTML link to a file in folder parent**

```
<a href="../folder/linktoyourfile.html" >Link</a>
```